# Create a Connected Graph With Two Types Of Edges

Tags: java, point

I want to build a graph that is connected and can only have horizontal or vertical edges. Edges are tracks/track switches.

- There are two types of tracks: `NormalTrack` and `TrackSwitch`.

  - NormalTrack: startPoint, endPoint.
  - TrackSwitch: startPoint, endPoint, secondEndPoint.

    - The first endPoint is the standard setting which is passable (there is a set switch command which can change the switch setting).
- All tracks (switch is also a track) have a unique identifier starting at 1.
- With the exception of the first track, a start or end point must always be connected to a start or end point of an existing track. Only one other track (normal track or track switch) can be connected to a point on a track.

**Here is an example and how the graph would look like:**

```
add track (1,1) -> (5,1)
ID -> 1
add switch (5,1) -> (8,1),(5,3)
ID -> 2
add track (1,1) -> (1,-3)
ID -> 3
add track (1,-3) -> (10,-3)
ID -> 4
add track (8,1) -> (10,1)
ID -> 5
add track (10,1) -> (10,-3)
ID -> 6
add track (5,3) -> (8,3)
ID -> 7
```

[image: Grapj]

I have a class `Point` which represents a Cartesian Point and a class `RailNetwork` where I am going to implement the graph. 
In my `Register` class I have a `Map<Integer, Track> tracks;` in which I save all tracks. In this class I also instantiated `RailNetwork network = new RailNetwork();`

I've already implemented the command interface. Now, I want to create the rail network.

Could someone show me how to implement this way?

**EDIT**

Here is my current implementation:

```
public class RailNetwork {
    private Map<Point, List<Point>> edges = new HashMap<>();

    // Add edge (two points)
    public void addEdge(Point firstCoordinate, Point secondCoordinate) {
        edges.computeIfAbsent(firstCoordinate, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(secondCoordinate);
        edges.computeIfAbsent(secondCoordinate, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(firstCoordinate);
    }

    // Return all edges
    public List<Point> getEdges(Point node) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(edges.get(node));
    }

    // Check if a set of edges is still connected after removing them
    public boolean isConnectedAfterRemoving(Set<Edge> toRemove) {
        Set<Point> notVisited = edges.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(d -> !toRemove.contains(new Edge(e, d)) &&
                        !toRemove.contains(new Edge(d, e))))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet());
        if (notVisited.isEmpty())
            return true;
        visit(notVisited.iterator().next(), notVisited, toRemove);
        return notVisited.isEmpty();
    }


    private void visit(Point next, Set<Point> notVisited, Set<Edge> toRemove) {
        if (!notVisited.remove(next))
            return;
        for (Point point : edges.get(next))
            if (!toRemove.contains(new Edge(next, point)) &&
                    !toRemove.contains(new Edge(point, next)))
                visit(point, notVisited, toRemove);
    }

    private void visitAndRemove(Set<Point> nodes, Point node) {
        if (nodes.contains(node)) {
            nodes.remove(node);
            List<Point> nextNodes = getEdges(node);
            for (Point next : nextNodes) {
                visitAndRemove(nodes, next);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Edge {
    private final Point source;
    private final Point dest;

    public Edge(Point source, Point dest) {
        this.source = source;
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this || !(o instanceof Edge)) {
            return o == this;
        }

        Edge edge = (Edge) o;
        return Objects.equals(source, edge.source) &&
                Objects.equals(dest, edge.dest);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(source, dest);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why my `isConnectedAfterRemoving()` method doesn't work. How can I fix this?
[image]

I also have a abstract class `Track` and two subclasses `NormalTrack` and `TrackSwitch`.

- `TrackSwitch(int id, Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Point secondEndPoint, int length, boolean switchEnabled)`
- `NormalTrack(int id, Point startPoint, Point endPoint, int length)`

How do I continue now..?

Comment: What do you mean 'the right way?', what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what classes I need and how I should implement this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to implement the RailNetwork class based on the tracks. Would a sort of linked list be what you're looking for? Or rather a circular tree, if that's even a concept.

Comment: @Scratte That would probably work too but I think a Graph makes more sense in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two classes `NormalTrack` and `TrackSwitch` and represent each track by an instance of that class. The classes store the id, the starting point and the end point(s) of the track.

Then you probably want to store for each point the list of incoming tracks as well as the list of outgoing tracks. A switch is a bit complicated in this setup since it has two endpoints. You probably also need a flag in the switch that tells which endpoint is currently active. Then, when you iterate over the incoming/outgoing tracks of a point and hit a `TrackSwitch` then you must first check if the point you are iterating is currently active. If not, you have to skip that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Please have a look at my Edit of my original question. How do I continue now..?

Comment: You did not show you definition of `Edge`. The problem may be there. Does `Edge` implement the `equals()` function? If not then your code may be comparing only references to edges, which will give wrong results. It seems you are creating a lot of new `Edge` instances in `visit`. Maybe the values in `edges` should be lists of edges, rather than points? Also, if you create two maps `Map<Point,List<Edge>>`, one for outgoing edges and one for incoming edges, then your code may get simpler?

Comment: I've added my Edge class now

Comment: I cannot spot an obvious mistake in your code. Maybe it is best to take a small example network for which the function does not work and then single-step through it with a debugger to find out where exactly things go wrong.